# How to implement a concatenation of logic variables in a table

Tags: boolean, logic, rules

I'm trying to implement a ruleset-type table for a bunch of questions in a form. I've got down the table for that ruleset, but originally I was going to just have them all in "AND"s. But I need to include ORs as well, and that means including brackets in to the equation. I'm not too sure how to implement it. I'm trying to figure out what the table needs or if it needs another table.

So this is an example of what I'm thinking.

```
{FieldRule: FieldRuleId, RuleId, FieldId}
```

When I get the other information, it'll evaluate to to True/False. How can I do it so I can do combinations of (Rule1 ^ Rule2) V Rule3?

Thanks!

Bump!

Last bump!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a Reverse Polish Notation system whereby I added the truth values to a stack as well as the `OR` and `AND` symbols. This seems to work very well! If anybody would like any further help on something like this, feel free to comment.